# Consume elements from ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I use a ConcurrentHashMap to buffer messages for a websocket.

Every 200ms the buffer is sent in one JSON String. afterwards I want to remove the entry from the Map.

This is not safe I guess, because during the foreach there might come new messages to the buffer.

```
String sendString;
for(String msg : buffer.values()){
    sendString += msg;
}
ws.send(sendString);
buffer.clear();
```

How could I safely remove the Elements?

Comment: why not queue? more suitable for producer-consumer scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the key and value.

```
StringBuilder sendString = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : buffer.entrySet()) {
    sendString.append(entry.getValue());
    buffer.remove(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); // only remove a matching value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map#remove()` returns value that exists in map prior to removal. In `ConcurrentHashMap` this is performed atomically, so you can safely consume the result:

```
StringBuilder sendString = new StringBuilder();
for (String key : buffer.keySet()) {
    String s = buffer.remove(key);
    if (s != null)
        sendString.append(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator explicitly:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (Iterator<String> it = buffer.values().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    result.append(it.next());
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: between `it.next()` and `it.remove()` can occur insertion to this key, and just inserted value might be removed.

Comment: The iterator does not iterate on keys but on values. According to javadocs ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, so it would not remove different key-value pair than retrieved by the iterator.

Comment: `BaseIterator#remove()`, on which value iterator is based, uses internal `map.replaceNode(p.key, null, null)` which removes a node by key, not value

Comment: iterator thread-safety means that modifications on it won't break consistent state of map itself, nothing more than that.

Comment: Unfortunately, iterator `remove()` don't return removed value, otherwise consuming on iteration could be implemented in easy and safe manner.

Answer (score -1):

Put your entire method block in a synchronized block. No other thread can write to the map while this code is being executed.

```
synchronized(buffer){
    String sendString;
    for(String msg : buffer.values()){
        sendString += msg;
    }
    ws.send(sendString);
    buffer.clear();
}

synchronized(buffer){
   buffer.put(key, msg);
}
```

Comment: oh, this will kill all benefits in concurrent environment that CHM offers

Comment: Yep.. but the OP needs a snapshot of the map at that instant which is not possible with just using the properties of CHM

Comment: @rahulroc "Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. " - javadoc comment on ConcurrentHashMap, JDK 7. So it's kind of a snapshot, but not necessarily at the time of creation.

Comment: That isn't actually true.  If it were a synchronized map maybe but CHM uses a different locking mechanism.